# How to create Angular2 library with multiple routes?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-ui-router, shared-libraries, components

I'm pretty new to Angular2 and I have a requirement to build a reusable library which will be consumed by multiple applications as a html tag.

This reusable library will have multiple pages like search, create, edit etc., which translates to multiple routes within the library itself. But most of the libraries on Git do not use router.

So my question is how to design my multi page reusable library?

Should I put everything (search, create, edit) in a single component and use ngIf to show/hide the sections within the same page. But I believe there should be some way to handle routing in a library without messing up with the consuming application routes.

Can you please suggest me a design approach. It would be of great help even if you can point me to some guide or post on how to build Angular2 library.

Comment: My question exactly. Did you find a way to achieve what you ask?

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid putting routing information directly in a library. Every application that builds up on your library might have different routing mechanisms: Different route names, different route guards, maybe even different routing libraries.

If you ship your library with pre-configured routing out of the box, you force users of your library to follow your routing ideas. If someone has a route "/search" defined already and you perhaps overwrite that route, that will cause frustration. Similarly, if someone decides to use a custom routing service rather than Angular's, they might not be able to use your library. Or if someone wants to put all views into one `Component` in a tabbed view, that might not be easily possible.

My recommendation is to ship an `NgModule` which declares a number of `Components`. Allow your users to use these components the way they want to. If they use all your components, they can set up one route per component. If they want to put all of them in tabs on one page, they can do that, too.

Answer (score 0):

This reusable library will have multiple pages like search, create, edit etc., which translates to multiple routes within the library.

This part you were saying is right. You can use route inside yoir library and navigate like normal angular application. Just make sure you have the corresponding components for those route inside your library.
Export you library Routing class to public_api.
Import you RoutingModule to your app along the library module.